# Браузер не переходит по заданной ссылке из index.php

Tags: php, phpstorm

Браузер не переходит по заданной ссылке из `index.php`

Выдает:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'Student.class.php'
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php')

Ссылка, данная мною в `index.php` на `Student.class.php` из папки 'core': 
`require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '../core/Student.class.php';`

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что данный сайт должен содержать вопросы(и ответы) только на русском языке.

Comment: Вы посмотрите на фимилию задавшей ))) Давайте вопрос переведем.

Comment: А по делу? ;(((

Comment: Проверьте наличие файла, и заодно проверьте, а нужен ли там `..` в пути.

Comment: @ixSci: да ладно, перевели же )